# I'm looking for a graphics library for Java

Tags: java, graphics

My task is to make a 2D 8-bit game with a couple of friends. All of us are fairly novice programmers, and only I have any experience with graphics programming (just a little though), so this will mostly be a learning experience for us. So, I have a few questions...

- What is a good graphics library for our needs?
- Does Java have any native graphics capabilities or do I have to use
  additional libraries? If yes, how are they?
- Is Java a good choice for    writing a game in? (we don't have to use
  Java)
- Will any graphics library allow you to make animations or any sort or do you actually have to code that kind of thing?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Java2D: http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

If you are not making serious game, try processing

http://processing.org/

althogh it's designed to make visual and interactive product, I think it is worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

The ACM (http://jtf.acm.org/index.html) library is good for basics.

Java has some native graphics, but libraries are far better.

Java is good for games (far better than python even with PYGame).  If your game is complex, then you definitely want to use C(++).

There are libraries that allow animations, although you could just program it yourself.

As previously mentioned, Processing is good for non-serious applications.  But if you want a full-fledged IDE then you definitely want Eclipse.